Hashicorp Vault KMS AutoUnseal without Access Key
Running Vault in EKS and the documentation states for KMS Auto unseal to work you require the below details in your config.
    seal "awskms" { 

    region = "us-east-1" 
    access_key = "xxxx" 
    seceret_key = " xxx" 
    kms_key_id = "pleasementionyour AWS KMS created in AWS Console " 

    }

This is all fine and I've got it working however seems a little bit insecure, does anyone know if you can do this with in IAM role instead?

As you stated - it is less secure to place sensitive values such as your AWS secret access key in your Vault configuration file.  The official HashiCorp documentation indicates that a more secure method of specifying these values is to use environment variables, as described in the Authentication subsection of the AWS KMS seal documentation.

Note: Although the configuration file allows you to pass in AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as part of the seal's parameters, it is strongly recommended to set these values via environment variables.

While the official documentation does not indicate that an IAM role can be leveraged to allow your Vault server running in EKS to talk to the KMS service, there are GitHub issues that have documented this very use case.
https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm/issues/368
https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm/issues/410
It appears that the user in issue 368 was successfully able to leverage an IAM role by specifying a few key parameters in the seal stanza of the Vault config file and then assigning a role.
Example Vault config from the aforementioned GitHub issue:
seal "awskms" {
  region     = "us-west-2"
  kms_key_id = "alias/my-vault-role-key"
}

